# Adding Entity to my custom annotation : Spring

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to create my own custom annotation like below and I am not aware if I can go ahead by implicitly putting a persistence annotation in any custom annotation.

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Entity
public @interface myOwnAnnotation{
    public String entityProperty() default ""; 
}
```

Any pointers?
Adding Entity annotation to my annotation created a problem.

Comment: Please clarify what problem has been created

Comment: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)


I can think that it the persistance annotations are not meant to be used like this. I wanted to clarify that

Answer (score 0):

JPA specification:

> 10.1   Entity
>
> The Entity annotation specifies that the class is an entity. This
>   annotation is applied to the entity class

When I reproduced your problem, Hibernate treated myOwnAnnotation as regular entity and failed due missing id.

In my understanding Hibernate correctly use specification, because applying @Entity to annotations is not predicted.

Comment: AFAIK '@Target(TYPE)' means that it is applied on Class level and yes '@Entity' is to be defined at class level but that should not stop me in using on other annotations right? If that is the case the same should hold true in case of '@Component' and '@Service' annotations. '@Service' annotation internally refer to '@Component' annotation

Comment: Good point. It seems to me Spring do not obey meta-annotations convention. Anyway, annotation meaning is specific for project. JPA specification says that @Entity is applied to entity class only